# How to input variable in dbcontext.SqlQuery query?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When creating this function in my Web API project controller everything works just fine.

```
public IQueryable<EquipmentApproval> GetUserEquipmentApprovalRejections(string username)
{
    return db.EquipmentApprovals.SqlQuery("select * from EquipmentApproval where rejectedReason is not NULL AND createdBy = 'hmbangu'").AsQueryable<EquipmentApproval>();
}
```

But When I try yo add a variable parameter like this:

```
...
    return db.EquipmentApprovals.SqlQuery("select * from EquipmentApproval where rejectedReason IS NOT NULL AND createdBy = @username" + new SqlParameter("@username", username)).AsQueryable<EquipmentApproval>()
...
```

I receive and error when I query the API, could someone tell me please tell how to add a variable to my dbcontext.SqlQuery() query. I also want my data to be returend as an IQueryable list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them comma separated

```
return db.EquipmentApprovals
        .SqlQuery("select * from EquipmentApproval where rejectedReason IS NOT NULL AND createdBy = @username",
            new SqlParameter("username", username))
        .AsQueryable<EquipmentApproval>()
```